# How to apply \n characters in text to automatically break lines

Tags: notepad++

With given text where \n are already present. I would like np++ to automatically consume those characters and show text with brokenlines instead of showing \n characters.
Is this possible?

Text example:

`'Failed to import test module: TestsDashboard\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/unittest/loader.py", line 434, in _find_test_path\n    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/unittest/loader.py", line 375, in _get_module_from_name\n    __import__(name)\n  File "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/omation_failed-run-investigation@2/Tests/TestsDashboard.py", line 2, in <module>\n    from Tests.BaseTestClass import BaseTestClass\n  File "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/omation_failed-run-investigation@2/Tests/BaseTestClass.py", line 4, in <module>\n    import psutil\nModuleNotFoundError: No module named \'psutil\'\n', 'Failed to import test module: TestsRelatedItems\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/unittest/loader.py", line 434, in _find_test_path\n    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/unittest/loader.py", line 375, in _get_module_from_name\n    __import__(name)\n  File "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/omation_failed-run-investigation@2/Tests/TestsRelatedItems.py", line 2, in <module>\n    from Tests.BaseTestClass import BaseTestClass\n  File "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/omation_failed-run-investigation@2/Tests/BaseTestClass.py", line 4, in <module>\n    import psutil\nModuleNotFoundError: No module named \'psutil\'\n', 'Failed to import test module: TestsReports\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/unittest/loader.py", line 434, in _find_test_path\n    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/unittest/loader.py", line 375, in _get_module_from_name\n    __import__(name)\n  File "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/omation_failed-run-investigation@2/Tests/TestsReports.py", line 2, in <module>\n    from Tests.BaseTestClass import BaseTestClass\n  File "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/omation_failed-run-investigation@2/Tests/BaseTestClass.py", line 4, in <module>\n    import psutil\nModuleNotFoundError: No module named \'psutil\'\n'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the extended search and replace to achieve this (Ctrl-H keyboard shortcut):

[image]

If by "automatic" you mean having it happen immediately when you paste, I don't believe Notepad++ supports that. You'd have to write a custom plugin.

Comment: Thank you for your time to write answer.